# How to search rows from a string and extract data from specific columns

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string called search containing multiple columns like this:

```
1     4     +/+
2     6     +/+
4     3     -/-
5     3     +/+
```

it is delimited by tabs. I want to sequentially go through row by row (I would assume using a for loop), search the row for if it contains "+/+" and if yes, add that value to a nested list containing the value from the second column. If there is no entry (for example 3 is not in the first row), then I want the paired value to be 0. So for the output of this specific case, it should be [[1, 4], [2, 6], [3, 0], [4, 0], [5, 3]].

So far I've tried

```
for i = 5
    if search[3] == '+/+'
        basefile[i]=(i, search[5])
    else
        basefile[i]=(i, 0)
```

what steps am I leaving out? I am very new to python.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the file open and have stored it in a variable f:

```
counts = 0
for line in f:
    if '+/+' in line:
        counts += 1
```

Or, if the whole thing is stored as a string, you can just use the split method (which will split the string at whitespace and put the non-whitespace parts in a list), iterate through the resulting list, and count.   So if s is your string:

```
counts = 0
for i in s.split():
    if i == '+/+':
        counts += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

lines.csv:

```
1   4   +/+
2   6   +/+
4   3   -/-
5   3   +/+
```

Here is an example:

```
lines = {} # create an empty dictionary to store key/value pair
with open('lines.csv','r') as f:
    orig_lines = f.read().split('\n') # split on new lines
    for line in orig_lines:
        line = line.split('\t') # split the line by tabs
        if len(line) < 3: # continue loop if line does not have 3 columns
            continue
        lines.update({line[0]:[line[1],line[2]]}) # dictionary with key/value ... value is a list with columns 2 and 3

# grab what the max value is from column 1
max_value = int(max(lines.keys()))
print("max:", max_value)
paired = [] # create an empty list

# if you want to take a look at lines uncomment this:
# import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
#
# and then you can actively inspect what is happening in the script
# as it is running
# print(lines) or print(lines['1'])

# we can iterate to the max_value
# since we are not sure which values in between are missing (ie "3")
for i in xrange(1, max_value + 1):
    i = str(i) # convert the int to a string so we can use it as a key
    try:
        print(lines[i])
    except Exception, e:
        # if we get an exception that means the key doesn't exist
        # lets add an empty one and continue to the next loop
        # (ie "3")
        paired.append([i,0])
        continue
    # if '+/+' is in the list stored in the key/value 
    if '+/+' in lines[i]:
        print(lines[i])
        paired.append([i,lines[i][0]])
    else: # matches any line that doesn't have '+/+' in it
        print(lines[i])
        paired.append([i, 0])
print(paired)
```

Note: There is probably a really simple solution using `itertools` or something in `collections`

Output:

```
bob@bob-p7-1298c:~/Desktop$ python test.py
('max:', 5)
['4', '+/+']
['4', '+/+']
['6', '+/+']
['6', '+/+']
['3', '-/-']
['3', '-/-']
['3', '+/+']
['3', '+/+']
[['1', '4'], ['2', '6'], ['3', 0], ['4', 0], ['5', '3']]
```